# Array initialization differences C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

Is there a difference between using curly braces or the assignment operator while defining an array in C++11?

```cpp
std::array<int, 2> a{1, 2}
// or
std::array<int, 2> b{{1, 2}}
```

and

```cpp
std::array<int, 2> = a{1, 2}
```

Comment: it does not compile. Typo? Did you forget the name of the array you declare?

Comment: @steveo314 _"double curlys usually means you will have an array of arrays"_ that's incorrect. The first brace will mean initialize the `std::array`, the second brace initializes the internal/underlying array via aggregate initialization. Single-braces also work because with aggregate initialization, sub-objects can be implicitly initialized by folding in the braces. [Older versions of clang used to actually warn with one brace for this reason](https://godbolt.org/z/17nn1rja4)

Comment: now it should compile..

Comment: Note that the `=` in the third example is **not** the assignment operator. It introduces an initializer. You can only assign to an object that has already been constructed.

Comment: So, the array will be initilized in the exact same way? It doesn‘t matter if i use the = or not?